# How to ignore test files in webpack with ts-loader

Tags: typescript, webpack

I have a project that runs the test files named "*.test.ts" with jest and ts-jest. This is fine but when I launch webpack, I get errors for the test files:

```
ERROR in /some/path/note.test.ts
(27,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name '
```

How can I fix the webpack config to totally ignore test files ?

Here is the webpack config:

```
const path = require ( 'path' )

module.exports =
{ entry: './src/boot.tsx'
, node:
  { __dirname: false
  }
, output:
  { path: path.resolve ( __dirname, 'app', 'build' )
  , filename: 'app.js'
  , publicPath: '/live-reload/'
  }
, devtool: 'source-map'
, resolve:
  { extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts', '.tsx']
  }
, module:
  { loaders:
    [ { test: /\.tsx?$/
      , exclude: /node_modules/
      , loader: 'ts-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[EDIT]

I used the test function to log seen files and the test files do not appear in there, so the problem is not on webpack including the wrong files but on typescript misbehaving (because tests work fine with jest).

Comment: ts-loader by default compiles all ts files, even files Webpack isn't told to bundle, like test files for instance that will throw errors due to missing globals. ts-loader may be configured to only compile files that Webpack is told to bundle as described by this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41289265/webpack-ts-loader-compiling-all-files-when-i-only-want-it-to-run-in-one-folder-f

Answer (score 22):

I ended up resolving this too, but in a different way, namely, adding the following settings to my `.tsconfig` file:

```
"include": [
    "./lib/**/*"
],
"exclude": [
    "./lib/__tests__"
]
```

Not sure why this didn't come up for the OP and company. Perhaps they already had those settings in their `.tslint` file (e.g. because their project had been generated or forked from another project).

But it looks like TypeScript (at least, as of 2.3.2) pays attention to these settings and ignores equivalent settings in `webconfig.config.js`.

Comment: You saved me a bunch of time of banging my head against the wall with webpack. Thank you!

Comment: I assume you're putting all your test files under `./lib/__tests__` right? If you exclude that folder in tsconfig, you'll lose intellisense from TS. I think a more reasonable solution is [this](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/544#issuecomment-316856503).

Comment: What if I want typescript to check test files during development, but I don't want to include them in my bundle?

Answer (score 7):

You can specify a function instead of the regular expression for the loader `test` property; this can give you a more control.

```
test: function (modulePath) {
  return modulePath.endsWith('.ts') && !modulePath.endsWith('test.ts');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer but it does not fix it (I added a comment). The problem seem to be with typescript not webpack filtering...

Answer (score 2):

Found it. My version of 'ts-loader' was behind and somehow did not manage to properly handle installed @types.

Rule of thumb: pack, build, transpile issues: **upgrade dev dependencies**.

Comment: I tried upgrading to the latest version, which at this time is 2.1.0, but I'm already at that version (and double-checked in the `node_modules` folder to make sure) and I'm still getting this exact issue! Did you do anything else, or just upgrade the version?

Comment: Make sure typescript is also updated to latest version (2.3.x currently)...

Answer (score 0):

The type definitions in Webpack 5 say that it will accept a function as part of `Rule.exclude`:

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/main/declarations/WebpackOptions.d.ts#L293

```
export type RuleSetConditionAbsolute =
    | RegExp
    | string
    | ((value: string) => boolean)
    | RuleSetLogicalConditionsAbsolute
    | RuleSetConditionsAbsolute;
```

If you are using ts-loader, use this function instead of passing strings and it should work. Folders will be excluded from the build, but you will still get type checking on the excluded files.

Say you want to exclude the `tests` folder:

```
{
    test: /\.tsx?$/i,
    use: 'ts-loader',
    exclude(value) {
        return !/tests/.test(value);
    },
}
```

You don't need to edit tsconfig.json in this case, but make sure that the `tests` folder is under `compilerOptions.baseUrl`, e.g. `baseUrl: "./src/app"` will not give type checks if your `tests` folder is in the root folder.