# Webpack regex test that matches *.ts but not *.d.ts

Tags: regex, webpack, aurelia, ts-loader

I am using Webpack (2.3.3) to build my Aurelia app in TS. However, since I am using `includeAll` option for AureliaPlugin (2.0.0-rc.2),  ts-loader (2.0.3) cries about d.ts files that has nothing exported emitting no output.

here is my rule for ts files: `{ test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/,  use: "ts-loader" }`

I need to change the test value in a way that it matches files named *.ts except *.d.ts. Can you help me please?

Note: I see there is already a similar regex question but that one did not work for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A regex that matches strings with `.ts` at the end but not `.d.ts` is

```
/(^.?|\.[^d]|[^.]d|[^.][^d])\.ts$/
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gEBQ0U/1). It is a POSIX style expression that will work with any regex engine.

**Details**

- `(^.?|\.[^d]|[^.]d|[^.][^d])` - either of:

  - `^.?` - start of string + any optional char
  - `\.[^d]` - a dot and any char but `d`
  - `[^.]d` -  any char but `.` and `d`
  - `[^.][^d]` - any char but `.` and then any char but `d` (this way, we match all but `.d`)
- `\.` - a literal dot
- `ts$` - `ts` at the end of string.

Alternatively, use a lookahead based solution:

```
/^(?!.*\.d\.ts$).*\.ts$/
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/gEBQ0U/2)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*\.d\.ts$)` - the string cannot end with `.d.ts`
- `.*` - any 0+ chars up to the
- `\.ts$` - `.ts` at the end of the string.

However, you might explore another option described in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41239152/3832970).

Comment: Never seen the function test in the wild so I had no idea about it. Ah, and the regex works, too. Thanks a lot!